# Producing normal map of a sphere

Tags: matlab

I searched Internet a lot, but it's hard to find how we can actually find a normal map of an object. Right now, I have to write a code which produces the normal map of a sphere. I mean [this one](http://images.search.yahoo.com/images/view;_ylt=A0PDoS70u5xSIzcAmPCJzbkF;_ylu=X3oDMTIybWtsZDM3BHNlYwNzcgRzbGsDaW1nBG9pZAM1YTEzYTA2NTY3MmM2NTNkOWU2OTI4MGNhMzUzNmE0MwRncG9zAzIEaXQDYmluZw--?back=http://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=normal%2bmap%2bfor%2bsphere&n=30&ei=utf-8&y=Search&type=dnld2msd_yl&hsimp=yhs-fullyhosted_003&hspart=ironsource&tab=organic&ri=2&w=512&h=512&imgurl=www.filterforge.com/filters/6487-normal.jpg&rurl=http://www.filterforge.com/filters/6487-normal.html&size=32.8KB&name=%3Cb%3ENormal%20Map%3C/b%3E&p=normal%20map%20for%20sphere&oid=5a13a065672c653d9e69280ca3536a43&fr2=&fr=&tt=%3Cb%3ENormal%20Map%3C/b%3E&b=0&ni=128&no=2&ts=&tab=organic&sigr=11jvgkppi&sigb=156tubgb6&sigi=11b62tki4&.crumb=5ZuwqkPnuPr&type=dnld2msd_yl&hsimp=yhs-fullyhosted_003&hspart=ironsource). My sphere should be defined with the set of azimuth and inclination, but we say that the numbers (azimuth and inclination) should be between 0 and 100 for example. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes! but i don't know how to assign azimuth and inclination. I mean how should I assign azimuth and inclination for each pixel of my image. I have tried it for a 5*5 image, but the results don't seem right

Comment: Please add your code and a definition of the map. Which normal should be mapped to which colour?

Comment: see: [Hairy Ball Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem). I think the answer is *not ideally*

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://galaxycityradio.com/2011/02/14/how-normal-maps-work/) is an explanation that provides a good insight at what is a normal map and how it can be created.

One way to create a sphere normal map in Matlab using the cartesian coordinate system would be:

```
% X and Y components of the normals vectors are between -1 and 1.
% The step number specifies the size of the output image.
range = -1:0.01:1;
% Repeat the range to build a matrix
X = repmat(range, [size(range, 2), 1]);
Y = flipud(repmat(range', [1, size(range, 2)]));
% These normals must be of unit norm, so find an Z component which
% solves sqrt(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2) = 1
Z = (1 - (X.^2 + Y.^2)).^0.5;
% Change the display range of X and Y to 0..1 instead of -1..1
X = (X + 1) / 2;
Y = (Y + 1) / 2;
Z = (Z + 1) / 2;
% Mask pixels outside the sphere (in which the Z component is complex)
X(Z ~= real(Z)) = 0;
Y(Z ~= real(Z)) = 0;
Z(Z ~= real(Z)) = 0;
% Build the map
map = cat(3,X,Y,Z);
imshow(map);
```

This builds a matrix `map` containing the X, Y and Z components of the normals of a sphere. You could use the [`sph2cart`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sph2cart.html) function to convert an azimuth and elevation to their equivalent X, Y and Z components.

Note that the normal map you referred to is flipped upside-down compared to the usual normal maps where green should be in the upper left corner and red in the lower right corner.